# How to use if condition inside a new instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have created a new instance but I want to disable the pagination based on `var enablePagination = false` but I don't know how to set the `if` condition inside that instance. If `true` then it has to work

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {           
  direction: 'vertical',
  // Need a condition to disable - true or false
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

Comment: I think you should look for a way to change the value of `el` like `el : enablePagination ? '.swiper-pagination' : ''`

Comment: @Bosco tried but did n't work

Comment: @Bosco any reference link for that format? I am totally new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `pagination.el` is `null` ([docs](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#pagination)), which means no pagination. As such you can use a ternary expression:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {           
  direction: 'vertical',
  pagination: {
    el: enablePagination  ? '.swiper-pagination' : null,
  },
});
```

Alternatively, you could define the configuration object separately and conditionally add the `pagination` object to it:

```
var config = {           
  direction: 'vertical'
}

if (enablePagination) {
  config.pagination = {
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
  }
}

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', config);
```

The latter is obviously more verbose given the first approach, though.

Comment: Thank you the method works. For the case of swiper library, there is `enabled` option available so that can be also used.

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Yes .. you just need to use `params` .. `mySwiper.params.pagination.el = '.swiper-pagination'` .. Sorry Rory but answered him because I don't want to waste your time reading the docs :) ..

Answer (score -2):

I think below example can help you out:

```
function fun(x)
{ 
console.log(x); 
}
fun(10<12?10:12);
```

output: `10`